# Is there a way to create a constructor of unknown number of variables in C++?

Tags: c++

I want to create a constructor, that can get an unknown number of ints so if someone wants to create a `new MyObj(1,2)` it should work, aswell as `new MyObj(1,2,3,2,5)` or `new MyObj(1,2,3,2,..,n)` .

Thank you

Comment: take in an array of ints rather than a defined set of ints?

Comment: How exactly are you going to use these variables?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a number of ways to achieve that (including the good old `var_args` as proposed as [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41170380/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-constructor-of-unknown-number-of-variables-in-c/41170437#comment69541223_41170380)). One of the simplest is using a [`std::initializer_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list):

```
class MyClass {
    std::vector<int> v;
public:
    MyClass(std::initializer_list init) : v(init) {}
};
```

Comment: Thank you !

Also, is there a way to get an uknown number of variables, of uknon type ?

Comment: @JohnTraveli I don't get your question? You need something like a `std::vector<std::any>`??

Comment: I assume that is what I want.

Comment: I want the constructor to be able to get for example 5 ints or five ints one string and one boolean .

Comment: any is not defined, compiler throws error

Comment: @JohnTraveli You should notice that [`std::any`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any) is a c++17 standard feature. Alternatively you can use [`boost::any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/any.html) for compilers that do not support the c++17 standard yet.

Comment: should I include a library for boost to work because its still throwing an error, I am using the latest version of xCode if this is any help to you , again thank you very much for your time!

Comment: @JohnTraveli In case you use boost, you should install it before of course.

Comment: Is this the only way to create a vector of unknown type of variables ? - its not that i dont want to use boost its that my partners dont have it.

Comment: @JohnTraveli Maybe some trickery with `std::tuple` but that needs at least all the type information resolved at compile time.

Comment: @JohnTraveli Extending that question for non uniform types of a _variables list_ is another (and very different) question. Consider asking another one instead of discussing that topic here in comments. You were primarily asking for the _varying number of variables_, not _varying types_ at the same time.

Comment: Thank you @πάντα ῥεῖ , also before I wave goodbye, the whole correct saying is " τά πάντα ῥεῖ ". I assume you are not Greek but the correct saying is τά πάντα ῥεῖ . Only with the τά can you have the correct meaning.

Comment: @JohnTraveli I'm preferring the shortcut (same translation at google at least). Also changing the nick it would disturb some kinda meme I've being setup so far.

Comment: Im Greek believe me when I say its not the same, and from what I understand you know Ancient greeks wouldnt say something if it was unnecessary, but never the less its true that you have a reputation with that name so changing it would be problematic

Comment: @John _"you know Ancient greeks wouldnt say something if it was unnecessary"_ You _hit the nail_. That's part of the philosophy ;)

Comment: Dont let your memes, be dreams :)

Comment: @JohnTraveli: ["πάντα ῥεῖ" was good enough for Plato](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heraclitus#Panta_rhei.2C_.22everything_flows.22).

Comment: @Lightness He was inventing _memes_ at their times may be ;)

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ when you are too deep in the dankmemes

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit I think it is good enough for anyone 1

Comment: @John It's more my personal philosophy rather than a _meme_. I'm not hiding under rocks or so. It's not that I'm not acknowledged here and people miss to read my profile.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, you can use `std::initializer_list` so long as the types are all the same.

Comment: Report from your repair station: _"Your crystal balls are SNFAU, and work fine as expected. You'll get our detailed bill listing all the positions for our checks in a few days."_ ;)

Comment: I'm afraid I just don't understand.